# How do I combine perform a Solr OR query between a spacial search and a regular query?

Tags: solr, geocoding, geospatial

The Solr [SpatialSearch](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch) documention hints that you can combine a spatial function such as `geodist()` with a regular query, but I've been unable to determine the correct syntax to do so.

Specifically this line ([in the geodist section](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch#geodist_-_The_distance_function)) caught my attention:

> Or you could use the distance function as the main query (**or part of it**) to get the distance as the document score:
>
> ...&q={!func}geodist()&sfield=store&pt=45.15,-93.85&sort=score asc

Following the store inventory example on that page, what I'd like to do is "find all stores either within a given city, or within a given distance of the city".  I can easily accomplish both seperately but am having a difficult time combining them.

Here's a pseudo-query that will hopefully clarify what I'm trying to do:

```
...&q=storecity:Buffalo OR {!func}geodist(store,45.15,-93.8)&d=5
```

The expected result would be every store in Buffalo, or within 5km of Buffalo.  The use-case is for very large cities, such as Los Angeles.  If I say all stores within 5km of Los Angeles it will only find stores within 5km of the coordinate, so looking for stores with a `storecity:"Los Angeles"` will include the lost results.

For bonus points, I'm also curious how I'd score to ensure stores within the city are ranked above those outside--but that's secondary and likely something I can figure out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following query to get the expected result.

> ..&q=storecity:Buffalo OR
>   _query_: "{!geofilt sfield=location pt=45.15,-93.8 d=5}"

Comment: Hi,I am also interested in this " find all stores either within a given city ",how can I do this with Solr?Does this need somethink like reverse geocoding so as to feed Solr with the city?